# xpath search on a csv file

Tags: file, csv, search, xpath

Need some help with the below question..

I have a xpath test condition which returns "TEXT" and "URL"  when the "value" is matched. This code is in a .xsl file

```
<xsl:when test="../../../../@name ='value1' ">
     <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;td&gt; TEXT1 &lt;/td&gt;  </xsl:text>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;td&gt; URL1 &lt;/td&gt;  </xsl:text>
```

```
<xsl:when test="../../../../@name ='value2' ">
     <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;td&gt; TEXT2  &lt;/td&gt;  </xsl:text>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;td&gt; URL2 &lt;/td&gt;  </xsl:text>
```

```
<xsl:when test="../../../../@name ='value3' ">
     <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;td&gt; TEXT3  &lt;/td&gt;  </xsl:text>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;td&gt; URL3 &lt;/td&gt;  </xsl:text>
```

```
<xsl:when test="../../../../@name ='value4' ">
     <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;td&gt; TEXT4  &lt;/td&gt;  </xsl:text>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;td&gt; URL4 &lt;/td&gt;  </xsl:text>
```

i want to store all the data in a csv file and use the xpath search on that file and return the results.

sample.csv file contains

```
value1,TEXT1,URL1
value2,TEXT2,URL2
value3,TEXT3,URL3
value4,TEXT4,URL4
```

If "value1" matches, then TEXT1 and URL1 shall be returned.

What code should i use to achieve this?

Comment: Your question is unclear:   1. Show a sample of your input XML file.  2. State clearly what output you'd like.  Is it the sample.csv file?  3. Clarify "*i want to store all the data in a csv file and use the xpath search on that file and return the results.*" because that sounds like you want to use XPath to query CSV, which would be very non-ideal.  4. Explain why you think you need `disable-output-escaping`.   Thanks.

Comment: @kjhughes: Basically i have a .xsl file which is applied on a xml file .

Comment: @kjhughes: Basically, i have a .xsl file which is applied on a xml file and rendering a dashboard which contains 5 columns .i am looking for specific strings on that xml file and and if it matches, i am appending additional data on 4th and 5th column. right now, the data for 4th and 5th column is included in the .xsl file itself. i want to seperate the data from the .xsl file. so thought of storing all the data in a txt or csc file and query that file